# Parse a CSV line containing embedded XML

Tags: python, xml, csv

I've got a CSV File with some XML Data. It looks like this:

```
meta1, meta2, sequence, "xml data"
```

The information in xml data sometimes contains commas.

What is the best way to slice this information into a tuple with only 4 elements?

I tried using string slicing, but sequence sometimes has 1 or 2 digits.

Using line.split(',') won't work either:

```
for line in lines:
  line.split(',')
```

Comment: split according to this regex `,\s*(?=(?:"[^"]*"|[^"])*$)` https://regex101.com/r/fM9gS2/4

Comment: Have you tried using [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Use the csv module which will handle the xml data correctly if it is properly quoted (as you indicate).

```
import csv

with open('input.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        meta1, meta2, sequence, xml_data = row
        # etc
```

Comment: Can I use the csv library if I have some fields with quotes?
ie: <name>"Mike","Smith"</name>

Comment: @EricZajac - No, you can't - but this doesn't sound like valid CSV data - the embedded quotes should be escaped; the convention being to double quote, e.g. `<name>""Mike"",""Smith""</name>`. What is producing the CSV data? If you can't change that, you may need to pre-process the incoming data to escape embedded quotes (which will be common for XML attributes).

Answer (score 0):

So if the style of the csv is always:

```
meta1, meta2, sequence, "xml , , data" #as you said maybe some commas in the xml data
```

Then use split but with maximum split parameter:

```
split(",", 3) #so at maximum there are 3 + 1 elements, because the maximum splitting is limited to 3 times splitting by ','.
```